# Class member initializer to initialize ifstream with error check?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use C++11 feature of class member initializer to initialize variables of class. The variables of class that I have are std::string and std::ifstream.

```
class A{
    std::string filename = "f1.txt";
    std::ifstream filestream = ....
public:
    ....
};
```

Is there any way to initialize filestream and also check for error at the same time using class member initialization.

What I want to do is, something similar to below :

```
class A{
    std::string filename = "f1.txt";
    std::ifstream filestream(filename);
    if(filestream.is_open()) .... // check if file cannot be opened
public:
    ....
};
```

Comment: Well, no. What do you want to do if the file couldn't be opened? You can check that in the constructor, and maybe throw an exception? But I think that this is bad practice.

Comment: @Rakete1111 thats what I was thinking as well .. I just wanted to make sure if I was doing it right .. so you suggest I do the ifstream initialization inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea myself :/ Sorry.

Comment: This is a bad practice. As Rakete1111 says check and initialize the member variable from the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write and call an inline lambda-expression that performs the appropriate checks; such a lambda-expression has access to the data members:

```
class A {
    std::string filename = "f1.txt";
    std::ifstream filestream = [&] {
        std::ifstream fs{filename};
        if (!fs)
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to open ifstream");
        return fs;
    }();
};
```

It may be clearer to separate out the logic into a reusable helper function taking `filename` as a parameter, e.g. a static member function:

```
class A {
    std::string filename = "f1.txt";
    std::ifstream filestream = openChecked(filename);
    static std::ifstream openChecked(std::string const& filename)
    {
        std::ifstream fs{filename};
        if (!fs)
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to open ifstream");
        return fs;
    }
};
```

Comment: I gave a further thought to this after your answer and would like to accept your answer. My thought after I saw your answer was, what if user choose to use different filename? in that case I might have to use mem-init constructor which overrides the class member initialization's filename.

Comment: @solti yes, that would definitely be the right way to override the default filename.